# Create a list from dictionary values and some conditions in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need some help with python and dictionary.

So the basically idea is to create a list that will contain several values on a python dictionary.
I parse each key of the dic, and then if the number of values is > 1, I check wether these values contain a particular prefix, if so I put the values that do not have the prefix into a list.

Here is the dic:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ACTGA': ['YP_3878.3', 'HUYUII.1'], 'ACTGT': ['XP_46744.1', 'JUUIIL.2'], 'ACCTTGG': ['YP_8990.1'], 'ACCTTTT': ['YP_8992.1'], 'ATGA': ['YP_9000.1', 'YP_3222.1'], 'AAATTTGG': ['ORAAA.8', 'OTTTAX']})
```

and a here is the `prefix_list = ["XP_","YP_"]`

Let me explain it better:

I would like actually to create a new `sequence_list` with value content.

So the basicaly idea is going though each key and if there are > 1 values, I put the n-1 values into the `sequence_list` depending on some conditions.

Here is an exemple :

- The first key is `'ACTGA'` where there are 2 values: `YP_3878.3` and `HUYUII.1`, then because `HUYUII.1` does not have any prefix into the `prefix_list`, then I put it into the `sequence_list`:

  `print(sequence_list):
  ["HUYUII.1"]`
- The second key is `'ACTGT'` where there are 3 values: `XP_46744.1`, `JUUIIL.2` and `JUUIIL.3`, then because `JUUIIL.2` and `JUUIIL.3` do not have any prefix into the `prefix_list`, then I put them into the `sequence_list`:

  `print(sequence_list):
  ["HUYUII.1","JUUIIL.2","JUUIIL.3"]`
- The third key where n value > 1 is `'ATGAAA'` where there are 3 values : `'YP_9000.1'`, `'YP_3222.1'` and `'HUU3222.1'`, then because `HUU3222.1` does not have any prefix into the `prefix_list`, then I put them into the `sequence_list`, AND because there is 2 values left with both prefix, I put the first one also in the `sequence_list` :

  `print(sequence_list):
  ["HUYUII.1","JUUIIL.2","JUUIIL.3","YP_9000.1","HUU3222.1"]`
- The fourth key where n value > 1 is `'AAATTTGG'` where there are 2 values : `'ORLOP.8'` and `'OTTTAX'`, then because both does not have a prefix into the `prefix_list`, I put the first one into the `sequence_list`:

  `print(sequence_list):
  ["HUYUII.1","JUUIIL.2","JUUIIL.3","YP_9000.1","HUU3222.1","ORAAA.8"]`

So at the end I should get the sequence_list such as:

```
["HUYUII.1","JUUIIL.2","JUUIIL.3","YP_9000.1","HUU3222.1","ORAAA.8"]
```

Does someone have an idea? I tried something but it is quite difficult and maybe totally messy:

```
sequence_list=[]
for value in dedup_records.items():
    if(len(value[1]))>1:
        try:
            length=len(value[1])
            liste=value[1]
            print("liste1",liste) 
            r = re.compile("YP_*.|XP_*.")
            newlist = list(filter(r.match, liste))
            if len(newlist)!=0:
                print(newlist)
                for i in newlist: 
                    if i in liste:
                        liste.remove(i)
                while len(newlist)>1:
                    liste.remove(newlist[0])
            else: 
                while len(liste)>1:
                    liste.pop(0)
            print(liste)
        except :
            continue
    for i in liste:
        sequence_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Your conditions are unclear (one time its the `n-1` value, another time it's the value without prefix, which in your example seem to happen both at the same time). What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: For each key, if there are one value, then I do nothing. If there are 3 values, I have to put n-1 values (3-1=2) values into the list. To decide wich one will go into the list, I first put all that have no prefix (if all have no prefix, I put the 2 first, If all have a prefix, I put the 2 first, If 2 have a prefix and one does not have, I put the one that does not have and the first one with a prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code much cleaner by using a function so that it is easier to read what is happening inside the loop.

Also, just personal preference, I'd suggest using `list_` as a variable name instead of `liste`, As the misspellings can be tough to work with.

The approach is to first split every list into two groups: one with prefix, and one without prefix. After that, We just need to verify that there is at least 1 item with prefix (in which case, append every items except the last one with prefix, and append all non-prefixed items), otherwise we need to leave 1 non-prefixed item, and append all the others.

```
dedup_records = {'ACTGA': ['YP_3890.3', 'HUYUII.1'], 'ACTGT': ['XP_46744.1', 'JUUIIL.2','JUUIIL.3'], 'ACCTTGG': ['YP_8990.1'], 'ACCTTTT': ['YP_8992.1'], 'ATGAAA': ['YP_9000.1', 'YP_3222.1','HUU3222.1'], 'AAATTTGG': ['ORLOP.8', 'OTTTAX']}

prefix_list = ["XP_","YP_"]

def separate_items_with_prefix(list_, prefix_list):
    '''separates a list into two lists based on prefix
    returns two lists: one for items with prefix
    another for items without prefix
    '''
    with_prefix = []
    without_prefix = []
    for item in list_:
        if any(item.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefix_list):
            with_prefix.append(item)
        else:
            without_prefix.append(item)
    return with_prefix, without_prefix


sequence_list = []
for val in dedup_records.values():
    if len(val) <= 1:
        continue #skip items with only upto 1 value in them
    with_prefix, without_prefix = separate_items_with_prefix(val, prefix_list)
    if with_prefix: #So there is at least 1 item in the list with prefix
        sequence_list.extend(with_prefix[:-1])
        sequence_list.extend(without_prefix)
    else: #there are no items with a prefix in the list
        sequence_list.extend(without_prefix[:-1])
```

Output:

```
print(sequence_list)
['HUYUII.1', 'JUUIIL.2', 'JUUIIL.3', 'YP_9000.1', 'HUU3222.1', 'ORLOP.8']
```

Comment: Than you very much, it is exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

If I get youre code right, you want to achieve this:

```
prefix_list = ["XP_", "YP_"]
sequence_list = []
have_interesting_prefix = lambda v: any(
      v.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefix_list
    )
for values in dedup_records.values():
  if len(values) > 1:
    sequence_list.extend(v for v in values if not have_interesting_prefix(v))
    prefixed = filter(have_interesting_prefix, values)
    if len(prefixed) > 1:
      sequence_list.append(prefixed[0])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but I only get `sequence_list = ['ORAAA.8', 'OTTTAX']` instead of `["HUYUII.1","JUUIIL.2","JUUIIL.3","YP_9000.1","HUU3222.1","ORLOP.8"]` ... The code I used is not working, maybe it is better to look at the exemple directly.

Comment: Hi @chippycentra, here is my output: ['JUUIIL.2', 'JUUIIL.3', 'ORLOP.8', 'OTTTAX', 'HUYUII.1', 'HUU3222.1']. Can you post the actual "dedup_records" contents?

Comment: Oh yes sorry for that, I updated the real content of the dic. But I only get now : `['HUYUII.1', 'JUUIIL.2', 'ORAAA.8', 'OTTTAX']` and from that  `'OTTTAX'` should not be in the list and `"YP_9000.1"` should be present.

Comment: Allright, now I got the problem right, I edited answer's code.